# D3.tip is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a d3.tip to my d3 infographic. According to the d3.tip documentation, I installed the d3.tip with Bower. When the install finished, my terminal screens shows:

[The terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NCjG.png)

I guess it was installed successfully.

But when I added d3.tip to my codes, the console.log keep showing "Barchart2.html:121 Uncaught TypeError: d3.tip is not a function."

Here is my code:

[The d3.tip part of my script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRxiV.png)

Can somebody tell me how to solve the problem, please?

Comment: Look in the file directory is the D3.tip source code there ? And have you referenced it in your HTML ?

Comment: `bower` installing the file is all well and good, but have you loaded it in your JavaScript?  `<script src="/path/to/d3.tip.js"></script>`?

Comment: Thank you @Mark The source code you provided is not working. Instead, I used another one: <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>, and it worked! I don't know why. However, although tips show up on my page, they are totally off the graphic and their positions are unstable. I am still figuring out why.

Comment: Thank you, @thatOneGuy! I put a source code in my HTML! But how should I put a D3.tip source code in my file directory?

Comment: is the D3.tip source code local with your JS, HTML and CSS files ? And have you referenced them in your HTML ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy It is not local, and I think I have referenced it in my HTML. I put this code there: <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

Comment: The error is because of the conflict with d3. I would suggest to create an alias of d3-tip library in your file and use it to initialise the tip function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to import d3-tip as imported d3 js.
I am assuming you have installed d3-tip correctly.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'; 
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
```

Then you can use it as below:

```
var tip = d3Tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').offset([-12,0])
.html(function(d) {
  /*  your code goes here */
});
```

This should fix your issue.